# Counting Unique instances in csv using excel

Tags: excel, vba, count, unique

In Excel, I need to get the number of unique occurences of a variable that is dependent on another variable.

For example: If tracking a unique cell site based on a call being made or received.  The column showing oringinating cell site and terminating cell site are static, but the direction of the call (another, separate variable per row) determines which one is pertinent from the perspective of the user.

1. I need the originating cell when the call is originated by the user, and the terminating cell when the call is being received by the user.
2. I also need the count of unique cells from that yield.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: see the [FAQ](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq). If you structure your question a little clearer and show the efforts you've tried, you will get more help, faster.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at formulas/formula auditing? this shows precedents and dependents.